# MPAndroidChart: remove padding between point lineChart

Tags: android, margin, padding, mpandroidchart

I have tried `holder.chart1.setViewPortOffsets(10f, 0f, 10f, 0f);` But it applies on the chart view.Insted of that i want to remove padding between horizontal lines. As shown in image there is (1,0) where (value,xaxisValue).

It added padding by default i want to remove that padding.

[image]

My code is:

```
     holder.chart1.setDrawGridBackground(false);
            holder.chart1.setDescription("");
            holder.chart1.setDragEnabled(false);
            holder.chart1.setPinchZoom(false);
            holder.chart1.setScaleEnabled(false);
 holder.chart1.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
            holder.chart1.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
            holder.chart1.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
            holder.chart1.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(true);
            holder.chart1.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
            holder.chart1.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

              holder.xAxis = holder.chart1.getXAxis();                       holder.xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            holder.xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);


            holder.rightAxis = holder.chart1.getAxisRight();
            holder.rightAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
            holder.rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
            holder.rightAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
            holder.rightAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        holder.rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
        holder.rightAxis.setAxisMaxValue(0f);
```

--> Replace it with highest/lowest value of your dataset

Comment: It does not make nay change in chart i tried. it is already MinValue is (0f) but it adds bottom padding and top padding.

Comment: Have you set axis dependency for dataset: `dataSet.setAxisDependency(AxisDependency.RIGHT);`

Comment: No i haven't set that dependency for dataset. Let me try

Comment: You saved my day. Thank You